# Angular unit testing promise reject without a catch

Tags: angular, jasmine

We have the following test:

`"should not call 'getCustomers' when 'getAvailableYears' throws"`

This used to work if we had the `catch` in our `getAvailableYears`, but now we don't need the catch anymore as we have a global error handling.

This is how `getAvailableYears` looks like:

```
this.service.getAvailableYears().then((availableYears) => {
    this.years = availableYears;
    this.loadCustomers();
});
```

That is the test, which used to work when we have the `catch`:

```
it("should not call 'getCustomers' when 'getAvailableYears' throws", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Arrange
    getAvailableYearsSpy = spyOn(service, "getAvailableYears").and.returnValue(Promise.reject("reason"));
    getCustomersSpy = spyOn(service, "getCustomers").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(createCustomersTestData()));

    // Act
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick();

    // Assert
    expect(getCustomersSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Now I get the following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): reason

How do I work with `reject` in case I don't have a `catch`? How do I test that something cannot be called if a promise has been rejected?

Answer (score 1):

If the Promise-Rejection isn't catched, it will bubble up and throw the error. So maybe you should add an expectation for the error like
`expect(getAvailableYearsSpy).toThrow();`

Comment: This does not work and should also not work. It's still showing: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): reason`

Comment: Maybe I should only delete this test as a **rejection** is a **rejection** and will never be caught in `then()` anyway